# How to export chart.js graph to svg in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, chart.js

I have a graph in my application, which was created with Chart.js library. My graph.js file looks like this:

```
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs';

const { reactiveProp } = mixins;

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'bottom',
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,
                callback(tick) {
                  return `${tick}%`;
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label(tooltipItem, data) {
              const dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
              const currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
              return ` ${dataset.label}: ${currentValue}%`;
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  },
};
```

And the component responsible for rendering it (i've cut some irreleveant details):

```
<template>
  <div
    class="container">
    <b>
      ...
    </b>
    <div
      class="graph">
      <graph
        :styles="graphStyle"
        :chart-data=graphData">
      </graph>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import Graph from './graph';
import {
  ...
} from '../../constants';

export default {
  name: '...',
  components: {
    Graph,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      ...
    };
  },
  watch: {
    ...
  },
  methods: {
    ...
  },
  computed: {
    ...
  },
};
</script>
```

I would like to export it to svg, and then post it to my api. I need to serialize it into a string and then send with post method, in json body. Do i have to use some another external library? How can i serialize it to svg? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Looking at [this issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1400), It looks like chart.js itself cannot export an svg, so it's pretty likely that the vue wrapper cannot do it, too. You most likely will need some other library for this.

Comment: Well it could be even another image-type, like png or something like that if possible.

Comment: There might be a way. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `png` is acceptable for you, there might be a way to do it. Keep in mind that I haven't tested this, but it should work by the looks of it.

Looking at the documentation of `vue-chartjs`, [here](https://vue-chartjs.org/api/#chart-js-object) it says that you can access the chartjs object with:

```
this.$data._chart
```

From there, you should be able to use its method for saving the chart as a png - `toBase64Image()`:

```
this.$data._chart.toBase64Image()
```